# What calls does the communications/calls API return?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-cloudcommunications

In the Microsoft Graph API Explorer there is an API sample for /communications/calls, in the Resources section. This endpoint does not appear in the API documentation. So what calls does it return? Should it return all active calls in the tenant? All calls involving bots? Or just calls involving one particular bot?

Comment: It returns the calls involving that particular bot. As mentioned in the document [call resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/call?view=graph-rest-1.0&preserve-view=true&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-v1.0#methods), The call resource is created when there is an incoming call for the application or the application creates a new outgoing call via a POST on communications/calls.  it just returns calls created by application.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v68Zr.png